# Make classes defined in cython monkey-patchable

Tags: cython, monkeypatching

I have a python extension partially written in cython. My problem is, if I instantiate python objects in cython code, the monkey patching seems to be ignored.

Pseudo-code `mymodule.pyx`:

```
cdef class ABC():
    pass    # some methods here...

cdef class DEF():
    def method1(self):
        return ABC(...)
```

Pseudo-code of monkey-patching in python code:

```
import mymodule as mm

class GHI(mm.ABC):
    pass

mm.ABC_ = mm.ABC
mm.ABC = GHI

def = mm.DEF(...)
ret_val = def.method1(...)
```

The type of `ret_value` is `< class 'mymodule.ABC'>` rather than `GHI`.

Any advice on how to make cython defined classes monkey-patchable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure that `ABC` is just a module-level variable, not a `cdef class`

```
cdef class _ABC():
    pass    # some methods here...

ABC = _ABC
```

You can then re-assign `mm.ABC` however you like. This obviously removes some small optimizations Cython makes when initializing the class, but that's the trade-off for flexibility.

If you need to access `cdef` attributes of `_ABC` then do:

```
cdef class DEF_(): # underscore to avoid using Cython DEF keyword
    def method1(self):
        cdef _ABC inst = ABC(...)
        inst.cdef_attribute = ... # works fine
```

This will produce a runtime error if the result of `ABC` is not an `_ABC` (subclasses are fine though)